Нужна ли запятая после "художественных"?
Я прочитал много полезных, в том числе художественных(?) произведений.

Правильно:
Я прочитал много полезных, в том числе художественных, произведений.
Пояснение
Оборот речи в том числе художественных обособляется как уточняющее определение со значением включения.
§ 22. Уточняющие члены предложения, пункт 4
Кой-где выглянули женские, большей частью старушечьи, головы 
(Т.); Их сопровождал небольшой плотненький человечек с 
флегматичным, почти заспанным, лицом (Т.); 

